# Llenar text area y seleccionar mi checkbox de acuerdo al valor

Tags: javascript, jquery

me pueden apoyar por favor

Resulta que tengo un campo  text area y me gustaria que al momento de escribir el valor del label de checkbox en automatico haga el cehck les muestro mi ejemplo pero no funciona.
Este es mi html

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" name="cbox1" value="first_checkbox">  <label for="cbox2">hola</label>
    
    <input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" name="cbox1" value="second_checkbox"> <label for="cbox2">juan</label>
    
    <textarea name="comentarios" rows="10" cols="40" id="text">Escribe aquí tus comentarios</textarea>
```

este es mi java script

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#text").on("change", function(){
    
 if (document.getElementById("text").value="hola" || document.getElementById("text").value="juan" ) {

        document.getElementById("check").checked;
    
    }else {
    document.getElementById("check").unchecked;
    
    }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si necesitabas buscar por coincidencias aquí te dejo una solución.

**Nuevo Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#text").on("keyup", function () {
 var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
    var MATCH_JUAN = text.match(/juan/g);
    var MATCH_HOLA = text.match(/hola/g);
    if (MATCH_JUAN) {
       document.getElementById("cbox2").checked = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("cbox2").checked = false;
    }
    if (MATCH_HOLA) {
        document.getElementById("cbox1").checked = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("cbox1").checked = false;
    }
  });
});
```

Si tienes dudas lo puedes escribir y con gusto te responderé.

Comment: Genial , mas o menos tenia la idea pero que sucede si yo quiero escribir  juan,hola al mismo tiempo me gustaria que los 2 se seleccionaran , como seria ??

Comment: Revisa el código nuevo que te acabo de agregar.

Comment: gracias , es lo que necesitaba ahora por ultimo , si en el campo se va autorrellenar con mi informacion de BD seria un Onchange no ?? para que al momento que caigan los valores de la BD se seleccionen en autonmatico  ??